# listview item cut style in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

How do I achieve the equivalent of the LVIS_CUT style for a listview item? It looks like it's not exposed by the framework? Should I P/Invoke?

Edit: LVIS_CUT is a Win32 style that affects the look of the item: It grays the item image. You can see it in action in Windows Explorer: Select a file and type Ctrl+X.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to "achieve the equivalent of the LVIS_CUT style" would be the following:

Use a function along the lines of

```
private void MakeCutList(ImageList sourceList, Color background)
{
   Brush overlay = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, BackColor));
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), sourceList.ImageSize);

   foreach (Image img in sourceList.Images)
   {
      Bitmap cutBmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cutBmp))
      {
         g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
         g.FillRectangle(overlay, rect);
      }

      sourceList.Images.Add(cutBmp);    
   }
}
```

to take the image list used by your ListView (i.e. listView1.ImageList) and add the "cut" versions of all the icons.  You might call this immediately after InitializeComponent in your form, like

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MakeCutList(listView1.LargeImageList, listView1.BackColor);
}
```

Then you could use code like this

```
private void SetCutState(ListViewItem lvi, Boolean isItemCut)
{
    int originalListSize = lvi.ImageList.Images.Count / 2;
    int baseIndex = lvi.ImageIndex % originalListSize;
    int cutImagesOffset = originalListSize;

    if (isItemCut)
    {
        lvi.ImageIndex = cutImagesOffset + baseIndex;
        lvi.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
    }
    else
    {
        lvi.ImageIndex = baseIndex;
        lvi.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
    }
}
```

to change the state of an item to being cut or not.

Once you get that working, you could try to put similar code into a subclassed version of the ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to when it's grayed out? Like when you do a "cut" on it? If so, I would just set the forecolor to Inactive or something along those lines. Not sure that you need to pinvoke for something like that.

Comment: Yes. But it also grays the item image. Do you have an easy solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my file explorer application ..

```
    private void MakeCutItem()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            Image img = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageIndex];
            Brush overlay = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, BackColor));
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), item.ImageList.ImageSize);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(overlay, rect);
            }
            item.ImageIndex = item.ImageList.Images.Add(img,Color.Empty);
        }
    }
```