# how to show hidden folder with hidden icon in c#

Tags: c#, listview, treeview, icons

Similar to windows explorer, I want to show hidden folders or files but with hidden icon. Most of you have seen that windows uses some kind of "Transparent" icon to show if the folder or file is in hidden mode. This icon also represents when you "Cut" a folder or file. Do I have to add a state image ? or I have to add hidden Icons?

Just to clarify what actually I am looking for, On a ListView, I am showing contents of a directory, but I couldn't find a way to distinguish between "[Regular Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqRZC.png)" and "[Hidden Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZAzU.png)". I am adding the functionality
to cut and paste. I don't know how to give the user an impression that the file or folder is in "Cut" mode.

Comment: Those are windows resources. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8931442/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr, I have extracted those icons, but I don't see any icon that seemed to be used for a hidden file or folder.

Comment: There is no dedicated icon for that.  Explorer generates a new icon from the original, modifying the colors of the pixels and making them look more washed-out.  This is not exposed as an api afaik.

Comment: for someone else is trying to do the same, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369024/listview-item-cut-style-in-net) might be helpful.